# How to free memory in Perl?

Tags: perl, garbage-collection

My code looks like:

```
 my %var;
 my %var_new={};

 while(1){
     while(my ($k,$v)=each %var){
            &a_sub($v);
     }
     %var={}; # A
     map { $var{$_}=$var_new{$_}; } keys %var_new;
     %var_new={}; # B
 }

 sub a_sub { #....} # will fill %var_new
```

My program's memory usage goes up and up.

It seems Perl doesn't free memory at Line A and Line B.

How can I manually make Perl to free up memory used `%var` and `%var_new`?

Comment: Why are you assigning a hashref to a hash?

Comment: `use strict; use warnings; use diagnostics` (the latter only during development)

Comment: Despite the bugs in the code you posted, there's no reason for the code you posted to use more and more memory.

Comment: Well, I don't think it's so much an issue of memory usage as the fact that you've set up an infinite loop from which there is no escape.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

IIRC, once Perl has allocated memory from the operating system, it holds onto that memory for the life of the process. Where possible, Perl will reuse memory it has already allocated rather than ask the operating system for more, but you won't see the memory used by a process decrease.

Comment: What you say is true in practice, but Perl *can* actually return memory to the OS. It's another question whether that's desirable in the general case.

Comment: How to forcibly release unused memory to OS?

Comment: @Luchostein Respectfully, that is not true. `perl -e '$a="a"x100_000_000; for(1..10) { push @b,"$_$a"; } sleep 10; @b=(); sleep 100;'` This will use >1GB for 10 seconds before dropping <1GB for 100 secs.

Answer (score 13):

If you had used `strict` and `warnings`, you would have seen:

> Reference found where even-sized list expected

Lines A and B don't do what you think they do. They actually assign as a key the stringified version of a reference to an empty hash, and undef as its value. Even if the hash is now almost empty, memory is not marked as reusable because you didn't use the proper statement for that.

Try using one of the following statements on lines A and B:

```
undef %var; # this one
%var = ();  # or this one
```

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to release memory back to the OS via `undef`. However there is a difference between `$var = undef;` and `undef($var);`

`$var = undef;` does nothing except resetting flags of the object. Size is still the same

`undef($var);` does actually delete the pointer and free's the memory of this object - if and only if this is the 'original' variable.

There is an interesting [Lightning Talk from Cees Hek - To undef or not to undef](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XvNTvqUYIAs)

For example the following code goes almost back to its originial memory usage after the call of `undef` (Tested on Perl 5.30.0 Fedora 31, libc 2.30)

```
#!perl

use feature 'say';

say "PID: $$";
say "Before Alloc";
<STDIN>;

my $large_string = "A" x 100000000;

say "After Alloc - Before undef";
<STDIN>;

undef($large_string);

say "After undef";
<STDIN>;
```

*But* ... this does not really mean that your complex datastructure will free all that memory after just calling `undef` on it.

The following example illustrates the problem:
The main memory consumer is `$sneaky`. After a call to `undef(%hash)` the memory usage stays almost the same because `$sneaky` is still around.

```
#!perl

use feature 'say';
use Devel::Peek;
$Devel::Peek::pv_limit = 15;

say "PID: $$";
say "BEFORE ALLOC";
<STDIN>;

my $sneaky = "A" x 100000000;
my %hash;
$hash{large_string_inside} = $sneaky;

say "After Alloc - Before undef";
say '$sneaky:';
Dump($sneaky);

say '%hash:';
Dump(%hash);

<STDIN>;

undef(%hash);

say "After undef";

say '$sneaky:';
Dump($sneaky);


say '%hash:';
Dump(%hash);

<STDIN>;
```

Even walking through the structure and calling `undef` on each element would not be enough (same goes for nested structures - you can walk them recursively but it won't make a difference).

```
while(my ($k, $v) = each %hash) {
    undef($v); # THIS IS NOT ENOUGH
}
```

*Why?* Because we did not delete the original `$sneaky`. The only way to give the memory back to the OS would be to call `undef($sneaky)`.

It also does **not** make a difference if you put a reference of `$sneaky` into the `%hash` like this `$hash{large_string_inside} = \$sneaky;`
You would still need to call `undef($sneaky)` and not `undef($hash{large_string_inside})`

Answer (score 1):

I think that using the `undef` function:

```
undef %var, %var_new;
```

might do the trick.
That is of course if you don't need what's inside those hashes anymore

Comment: Setting `%var` and `%var_new` to `{}` should have the same effect.

Comment: It doesn't. Inspect with Devel::Peek.

Comment: @KeithThompson No, setting `%var` and `%var_new` to `()` should have the same effect.

Comment: Undefining the hashes should free the memory for other use within the perl process, but will not decrease the total memory used by the process.

Comment: @chepner not true. It all depends on _what_ is in the hash. if you don't use any variables to populate your hash for example `$hash{thing} = "A" x 10000000;` it will free all memory and also give memory back to the OS. However if you would do `$hash{thing} = $var` only the hash itself is free'd but since `$var` is still around memory usage will probably stay almost the same.